# webview javascript interface to update Autocompletetextview

Tags: android, webview

I'm a beginner of Android and new to Stackoverflow. So excuse me for my silly question. However I found no solved solution here, so posting it as a new question.

I've an activity with an Autocompletetextview and a webview. I want on clicking a hyperlink in webview to fill some text in Autocompletetextview. So I've called Javascript in the webpage which in-turn calls Javascript AppInterface. In interface function, I want to update Autocompletetextview text.

I'm able to collect the text from javascript. But while setting the text of Autocompletetextview, my application is crashing.

**WebAppInterface.java**

```
public class JsInterface {
 @JavascriptInterface
 public void NewText(final String text)
{
Log.d("New_Text", "" + text); //Works fine till here.
((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AutoCompleteTextView SearchTextbox = (AutoCompleteTextView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        SearchTextbox.setText(text);
    }
   });
 }
}
```

**Error on App Crash**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaBridge
 Process: com.test.xxx, PID: 22102
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
 at com.test.xxx.WebAppInterface$1.run(WebAppInterface.java:102)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I want to know if my approach to update UI component is correct?
If yes, what changes will resolve the error and will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

is self-explanatory enough. You're casting `mContext` to `Activity` while it's not an instance of Activity class.

You can add a method called `setAutoCompleteTextView` to your `JsInterface` class, in which you can hold a reference to that auto complete text view.

```
public void setAutoCompleteTextView(AutoCompleteTextView textview){
    this.mTextView = textview;
}
```

And in the JavaScript interface method, use it like `this.mTextView.set...()`.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

This means your `mContext` varible at the problematic line is an `Application` object not an `Activity`, so refer to the `Activity` where you assign it not to the `Application`.